# Rubocop rule so that multiline conditional assignments start the condition on the next line

Tags: ruby, lint, rubocop

In rubocop, I'd like to enforce that multiline conditional assignments indent all lines within the conditional from the beginning of the line instead of after the assignment operator. It should force the conditional to the next line. Did a bunch of searching / experimentation but couldn't find a solution. Best configuration I found was:

```
Layout/EndAlignment:
  EnforcedStyleAlignWith: "keyword"

Layout/MultilineAssignmentLayout:
  EnforcedStyle: "new_line"
```

Those rules allow both of the following; would like to exclude and ideally autocorrect the first into the second.

```
# bad
mode = if keys.count == 0
         'Solo'
       else
         'Multi'
       end

# good
mode =
  if keys.count == 0
    'Solo'
  else
    'Multi'
  end
```

Not interested in using the ternary operator since this needs to support large conditional blocks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not extract the "large conditional blocks" into private methods? I would consider such "large conditional blocks" as a code smell.

Comment: We've solved these issues in both ways in different parts of the code. A linting rule to prevent large conditional blocks would also be nice.